# fetching phone number according to name

Tags: android

i want to get number from name that i select from spinner how can i do.i think first i want to id for particular name.can any one help me.

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View arg1, int pos, long arg3)

```
        {

            String name,phoneNumber;
            name=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

            String[] projection1 = new String[]{
                    People._ID,People.NAME,People.NUMBER
                 };

            Cursor cur=getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection1,People.NAME+"="+name , null, null);               

            phoneNumber=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "number="+phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           /* cur.moveToFirst();
                 if(cur.moveToFirst())
                 {
                     do
                     {



                     }while(cur.moveToNext());

                 }*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you read the `Contacts` for the first time, save them to `ArrayList` , make your `Custom  Class` to hold necessary information about each `Contact` like name and number, then put them into `HashTable<String,CustomClass>` , the key is the `Contact` number, then you can quickly get it from the `HashTable`

Comment: thanks for reply MoshErsan but can we not do it by query?spinner select name it will fetch particular id and according to id we can fetch number is this possible

Comment: where you fill the spinner, in another way, from where you got the names? so you made the query before !!

Comment: ye i use that is my code to fill the spinner and i want number according to selected code...

Comment: adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,name);
         spinner.setAdapter(adapter); after do-while loop